# How to wait for receiving result between 2 different class:

Tags: android, listener

I have a program that has two classes 1 and 2. My program has a menu that opens and closes in the first Class (1).

**This is Class1:**

```
public class Class1 extends AppCompatActivity {
 ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This function open menu correctly.
                openMenu();   
            }
        });
    }
        private void openMenu() { 
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        // The openDrawer function in class 2 opens the menu. 
        // When it's closed in class 2, notify Class 1 here.

        }
}
```

And **this id my Class2:**

```
public class Class2 extends DrawerLayout {

        public void openDrawer(View drawerView) {
        super.openDrawer(drawerView);
        currentSideBar = (SideBarWithBg) drawerView; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        y = ev.getY();
        if (y  > 400) {
            closeDrawers();
            // Notice to class 1 that the menu is closed.
            ...
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }

    }
}
```

In class 1, I open the program menu using of the `openMenu` function. The program should wait in `openMenu` function to the close menu command in class 2, to exported.. The command to close the menu in class 2 is exported using of `dispatchTouchEvent` function.

Now, **my question is:** How can I receive the closing menu command in `openMenu` function of class 1 to close that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved with these 5 steps:

**1. Create Interface:**

I create `OnCloseMenuListener`  interface like this:

```
interface OnCloseMenuListener {
    void setOnCloseMenu();
}
```

**2. Inmlement the interface in Class1:**

In `Class1`, I implement this Interface:

```
public class Class1 extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnCloseMenuListener
```

**3. Override `setOnCloseMenu` method :**

In Class1, I override the `setOnCloseMenu` method of my interface class:

```
@Override
public void setOnCloseMenu() {
    Log.e("<<O>>", "The menu closed...");
}
```

**4. Create `CloseMenu` method:**

I create this `static` method in `Class1`, when menu closed in `Class2`,it called:

```
public static void CloseMenu(OnCloseMenuListener close, boolean isClose) {
    if (isClose)
        close.setOnCloseMenu();
    }
}
```

**5. Calling `CloseMenu` in `Class2`:**

In `dispatchTouchEvent` method of `Class2`, when the condition was `true` and the menu closed, I trigger the `Class1` using of `CloseMenu` method:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    y = ev.getY();
    if (y  > 400) {
        closeDrawers();

        // This code notify Class1
        Class1.CloseMenu(new Class1(),true);

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

I hope it will be useful for those who came up with this problem later.

Answer (score 1):

[**EventBus**](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) might help you achieve that.

**This is how it work**
[image: How EventBus works]

Create custom event for each action and the subscribers will act accordingly. [Check out this article](https://medium.com/@vatsalbajpai/eventbus-for-android-4afa17863884)